# MEAN stack - guest accounts that can read our data

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, meanjs, mean.io

What is the best way to create a guest account system whereby we can uniquely identify a guest via their browser or device and still let them read the same data in the same way our users with authenticated accounts can?

So basically we can let our guest account holders have read access but not write access.

So we want:

1. To uniquely identify guest users
2. Save their session data in the same way as our authenticated users
3. Simply limit their access to certain requests that only authenticated users can make

Is there a good pattern to use to allow some users of our service to have guest accounts - my main question is what info can we use to identify a guest? Probably not IP address - but maybe a device ID for a mobile phone or something?

Comment: sounds like you want a cookie with a session id..

Comment: I would just limit the access to certain routes.  So guests would have access to all GET's but not PUTs.  There's generators like angular full stack that provide a template for creating user roles so you just pass into the controller like: router.put('/myroute', Auth.authenticated, controller.addData);